# Override span style within styled header

Tags: html, css

This should be a simple solution, but I can't seem to figure it out. Take a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9EKu/1/). Why can't I override the font-size of the second span? Here is the code:

html:

```
<h1>
    <span>hello </span>
    <span id="span2">world</span>
</h1>
```

css:

```
h1
{
    font-size:2em;
}
h1  #span2
{
    font-size:1em !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you set the font-size of `<h1>` to 2em. the span inside of your `<h1>` is 1 em that means something like 100% of the inherited font-size. see what happens if you set the font-size of `span2` to `0.5em`
and btw, your first span is missing a proper ending tag.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Thank you. I can use pixels and size how I want :)

Answer (score 1):

add

```
 #span2     {
  font-size:1em !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
h1 span
{
    font-size:2em;
}
h1 span#span2
{
    font-size:1em !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

em's are relative units of measurement. You could almost substitute "%" instead of "em". So, when your span rule has "1em", it's interpreted as "make me 100% the size of my parent", thus, no effect.

If you want it to be half the h1 size, you need:

```
#span2 {
   font-size: .5em;
}
```

[See this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9EKu/1/).